# Unknown graphics extension and \animategraphics unrecognized command issue

Tags: animate

I just updated Tex Live to 2022 version. I am trying to run this on Tex Studio however I keep getting the error: "
Unknown graphics extension: .dict. \end{frame}". Also It is saying that \animategraphics is an unrecognized command.

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usepackage{animate}  

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \animategraphics[autoplay,loop]{1}{rwalk2bm}{0}{19}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Anyone know why this is not working? I tried compiling with PDFLaTex, LuaLaTex and XeLaTek. Also rwalk2bm is a PNG file.

Comment: Just to make sure: your png file does contain animated graphics, i.e. at least 20 frames? // Did you verify, the package is installed?

Comment: Here with TeX Live 2022 with LuaLaTeX, it compiles correctly. Perhaps something went wrong with your TeX Live installation, or you have some setting somewhere getting in the way?

Comment: Looks like you didn’t read ch. “Using the package” carefully enough.

Comment: Put your example listed above and the image files `rwalk2bm0.png` through  `rwalk2bm19.png` in a newly created, initially empty directory and try compiling again. Make sure that all image filenames are spelled correctly and that all files have a *lower case* extension `.png` (not `.PNG`).

Comment: @MS-SPO the package is installed. Also i need 20 frames for it to work?

Comment: show the complete log-file of your document.

Comment: @alpastor, your statement says, it shall start at frame 0 and continue untill frame 19, which are 20 frames to me :) // See also AlexG's statement.

Comment: Once more: According to your example, the graphics files ***must*** be spelled ***exacly*** as `rwalk2bm0.png`, `rwalk2bm1.png`, ..., `rwalk2bm19.png` and all be existent in the current directory. Anything else will fail, such as `rwalk2bm.png` (missing number), `rwalk2bm-0.png` (wrong spelling: hyphen), `rwalk2bm0.PNG` (wrong spelling: uppercase extension).

Comment: @MS-SPO sorry, I read that as the package in general will only work if there are 20 files. I found my problem though. I have a png with 20 photos inside of it. What I needed to have was 20 separate png's each titles rwalk2bm0.png, ..., rwalk2bm19.png.

Comment: Please post your working version as Answer, indicating file requirements. Thanks

Comment: @alpastor PNG is a single-page format. Are your animation images glued together side-by-side within a single PNG file?

Comment: @MS-SPO I ran into another issue. The document complies fine after putting all the rwalk2bm0.png, ..., rwalk2bm19 files in the working directory. But when I compile, the gif does not play. Only the first frame is shown with the text "animation by animate 2022/ 02/ 21" written through it.

Comment: Just to remind you, this is not a discussion forum. Please add to your post, taking the aboves commetns into account, i.e. provide all that's needed. BTW, did you re-read said chapter? Looks like your preamble was a bit too slim ...

Comment: @AlexG I fixed that issue, all the files are correctly spelled and are in the directory. Before all the files were in one png file. However after doing that the gif still isn't playing, only the first frame is showing.

Comment: Now you need a PDF viewer with JavaScript support, such as Acrobat Reader, or Okular if you are on Linux. Note that AR has no JavaScript support on mobile devices (Android, ChromeOS, iOS).